# Cannt read img width added from css file

Tags: javascript

I checked it in two newest browsers.

JS code:

```
      window.onload = function () {
                                alert
      (document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByTagName ("img") [0].style.width);
                            }
```

HTML code:

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body> 
      <div id="slideshow">
      <img src="slides/1.gif">
      <img src="slides/2.gif">
      <img src="slides/3.gif">
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

CSS code:

```
      #slideshow img {
                display : none;
                width : 300px;
                height : 200px;
            }
```

But I have empty string from alert. Why the error (no errors in Firebug) occurs? Can I read style added from css file at all ? http://jsfiddle.net/HM47Q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) instead.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width"));
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HM47Q/5/)**

Comment: That's the width of the DIV. `getElementsByTagName("img")[0] is missing`.

Comment: @alexP - example updated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are retrieving inline style.

use this:

```
   var element = document.getElementbyId("#slideshow").getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
   var width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this solution requires jQuery, which the question isn't tagged with.

Answer (score 1):

Empty images doesn't have width/height

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/HM47Q/2/

```
var firstImg = document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByTagName ("img") [0];

alert ( window.getComputedStyle(firstImg).width );
```

You have to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) in order to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is working::
Make your image display:block,otherwise it will return 0.

```
<!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <style>
      #slideshow img {
                display : block;
    border:1px solid;
                width : 300px;
                height : 200px;
            }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body> 
      <div id="slideshow">

          <img src="slides/1.gif">
      <img src="slides/2.gif">
      <img src="slides/3.gif">

      </div>

        <script>
       window.onload = function () {
                                alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].clientWidth);
                            }
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```